# Converting a PDF file to a Text file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, text, converters

I've been on it for several days + researching the internet on how to get specific information from a pdf file.

Eventually I was able to fetch all information using Python from a text file(which I created by going to the *PDF file -----> File ------> Save as Text*).

The question is how do I get Python to accomplish those tasks(Going to the PDF file(opening it - is quite easy open("file path"), clicking on File in the menu, and then saving the file as a text file in the same directory).

Just to be clear, I do not require the pdfminer or pypdf libraries as I have already extracted the information with the same file(after converting it manually to txt)

Comment: There's a [web app](http://pdf2html.tabesugi.net:8080/) and a module that will convert [pdf2txt.py mypdf.pdf](http://euske.github.io/pdfminer/index.html#install). Look into it

Comment: Yeah I know about it. But I want to achieve this process by automating the process eventually, so I need it to be via python commands. And as I said I was able to do this operation without a webapp simply by going into the pdf file and saving it as text - that's what I want to tell python to do. Thank you for your feedback, Clayton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pdftotext.exe that you can download from http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html and then execute it on your pdf files via Python:

```
import os
import glob
import subprocess

#remember to put your pdftotxt.exe to the folder with your pdf files 
for filename in glob.glob(os.getcwd() + '\\*.pdf'):
    subprocess.call([os.getcwd() + '\\pdftotext', filename, filename[0:-4]+".txt"])
```

At least it worked for one of my projects.

Comment: Thanks pawelty, but it doesn't seem to do anything.'[: import os
import glob
import subprocess

for filename in glob.glob(os.getcwd() + 'C:\PDFs\ConfirmationPDF.pdf'):
        subprocess.call([os.getcwd() + 'C:\PDFs\pdftotext.exe', filename, filename[0:-4]+'txt']) '.  The pdf's name is confirmationpdf.pdf and i saved the pdftotext.exe to that same location. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: first change your working directory to C:\\PDFs\\ with os.chdir('C:\\PDFs\\'). When you change the working directory you don't need to change anything in the code I provided. After it's done just check your folder to see if the txt files are there. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Yup,Tnx :) it worked but the text inside contains UTF-8 encoding, and it does not transfer that data into the text file, basically taking numbers and english letters ,Any way around it?

Comment: Not sure, maybe someone else will know... Converting pdf to text is tricky and often causes problems...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @Jenny_V Could you pastebin your results?

Comment: A#ebill#embeddedEmail#vadik18@gmail.com#Z

1251026416  /       


12/05/2016  13/04/2016   20147366  
13/05/2016   
1 :(  )    "   "  

    17  ,36 " 7566132   vadik18@gmail.com

59.31
59.30 10.08 69.39

,  
 
"   " 17.00% "
"     "

69.39
----Hope this is coherent enough. As I said some non english text is missing..

Answer (score 0):

You can use "tabula" python library. which basically uses Java though so you have to install Java SDK and JDK.
"pip install tabula"
and import it to the python script then you can convert pdf to txt file as:
tabula.convert_into("path_or_name_of_pdf.pdf", "output.txt", output_format="csv", pages='all')
You can see other functions on google. It worked for me.
Cheers!!!